# Insert " in correct form in a String

Tags: java

I want to to input this link in to the string.

```
String url=www.test.com;
String link=<a href=url>contact info</a>
```

How can I write this ?

Comment: "want to", not "wanna"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do:

```
String url = "www.test.com";
```

You can use `\` character to indicate that we want to include a special character, and that the next character should be treated differently. `\"` indicates a **double quote character** and not the termination of the string.

```
String link = "<a href=\"" + url + "\">contact info</a>";
```

A character preceded by a **backslash** is an **escape sequence** and has special meaning to the compiler. The following table shows the Java escape sequences:

### Java Escape Sequences:

[image]

For More information check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Answer (score 2):

First, let's assume you have:

```
String url = "www.test.com";
```

(Note the quotes around the string.)

To create your `link` string, you'd do this:

```
String link = "<a href=\"" + url + "\">contact info</a>";
// Note ---------------^^-----------^^
```

To put a `"` *inside* a string literal, you put a backslash in front of it. This is called "escaping" the quote.

Answer (score 0):

First have the **url** value within **quotes** ,then **concat** the value in the **link** string.

```
    String url="www.test.com";
    String link="<a href="+url+">contact info</a>";
```